# Generate dynamic filenames with grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Is it possible to generate dynamic filenames outside the built-in grunt tasks (e.g. `concat` or `min`)? I tried to use something like `<config:concat.dist.dest>` or `<%= dirs.dest %>` as it is described in the docs. But this never gets interpreted / compiled, it just writes out the string.

**Update:**
That's what I tried based on jakub.g's answer. My grunt.js looks like this:

```
// ... grunt file contents
    jquery: {
      exclude: [],
      version: '1.8.3',
      dest: '../dist/js/jquery-' + grunt.task.directive('<config:jquery.version>') + '.js',
      minify: false
    }, // ... even more grunt file contents
```

`grunt.task.directive('<config:jquery.version>')` returns `null`. So the filename was named `jquery-null.js`.

I then tried `grunt.template.process('<%= grunt.jquery.version %>')` and `grunt.config.process('<%= grunt.jquery.version %>')`, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hidden under the hood of Grunt magic in the built-in tasks and in fact not documented clear enough.

You need to use sth like  [`grunt.task.directive(dest)`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/api_task.md#directives) to evaluate things like `<config:..>`. in a custom task.

For `<%= foo %>`, have a look at [Grunt templates](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/api_template.md).

Furthermore, wildcards like `*` and `**` and also not expanded by default, if you want to use them in custom tasks, you may use `grunt.file.expandFiles()`.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction... I can't get it to work, though. Please see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: You should leave the code in `grunt.js` file untouched (with `<config:..>` or `<%= foo %>` in it), but change the code inside the `jquery` task by reading `dest` and performing `grunt.task.directive` and so on that value.